# What is the best way to split start and end time into specified intervals in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For ex:

```
@StartTime = '7/27/2022 7:55 AM'
@EndTime = '7/27/2022 5:07 PM'
@Interval = 30 minutes

After rounding (Round to hour and half hour):
@StartTime = '7/27/2022 8:00 AM'
@EndTime = '7/27/2022 5:00 PM'

Output:
8:00 AM - 8:30 AM
8:30 AM - 9:00 AM
.....
.....
4:30 PM - 5:00 PM
```

How can I do this in TSQL in SQL Server?  Thanks!

Comment: First, don't use localized date literals, especially not the format that's not used by 95% of people. Second, use a Calendar or in this case a Time or Shift table with precalculated entries for all the intervals you want. This could be as easy as `select * from Shift where time between @StartTime and @EndTime`. You don't need runtime with such a table

Comment: So SHIFT table contains just one column with start time of specified interval?

Comment: @WinFXGuy It could if you want to assume. A bit more straightforward to include both columns and join as in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2fd37304779436fb4b0ddc8080442235). Note this does not include the rounding - simple searching should find suggestions for doing that.

Comment: Aside: Using `between` is almost always the wrong thing for these sorts of ranges which usually represent a [half-open interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology) that doesn't include the end time. Don't try to finesse the last fraction of a second, e.g. by subtracting 3ms from the end time. Just use logic of the form `StartTime <= SomeTime and SomeTime < EndTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME2(3) = '7/27/2022 7:55 AM';
DECLARE @EndTime DATETIME2(3) = '7/27/2022 5:07 PM';
DECLARE @IntervalMinutes INT = 30;

SET @StartTime = DATEADD(Minute,-DATEPART(MINUTE,@StartTime) % @IntervalMinutes,@StartTime);
SET @EndTime = DATEADD(Minute,-DATEPART(MINUTE,@EndTime) % @IntervalMinutes,@EndTime);

WITH time_intervals AS (
SELECT
    CONVERT(TIME,'00:00') as time_stamp
UNION ALL
SELECT
    DATEADD(MINUTE,@IntervalMinutes,next_cte.time_stamp)
FROM time_intervals next_cte
WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE,@IntervalMinutes,next_cte.time_stamp) <> '00:00'
)
SELECT
    time_intervals.time_stamp [From time],
    DATEADD(MINUTE,@IntervalMinutes,time_intervals.time_stamp) [To time]
FROM time_intervals
WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN CONVERT(TIME,@StartTime) AND CONVERT(TIME,@EndTime)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

This is using a recursive cte to generate a table with set intervals. Just use localisation when converting to text-datatypes to get AM/PM or handle it in presentation layer.